# default timeout for JAX-WS client

Tags: web-services, timeout, cxf, jax-ws

We are calling web service for which using `cxf-codegen-plugin` for code generation from WSDL and have configured JAX-WS client in Spring xml as follows:

```
<jaxws:client id="abcApiInterface" serviceClass="abc.api.AbcApi" address="${xyz.abcApi.endpoint}" />
```

And we have our webservice interface generated by Apache CXF 3.0.3. We are seeing timed-out when calling that service, we have not specified any timeout on client side so just want to know what's the default value for timeout for JAX-WS client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default value is 30 seconds for connection timeout and 60 seconds for receive timeout.

See: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Theclientelement

Comment: One more clarification: can we keep the `ConnectionTimeout` to default value of **30 seconds** and increase the `ReceiveTimeout` to **300 seconds**?

Comment: Sure that's possible

Comment: You could find an example here (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49941#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-HowtoconfiguretheHTTPConduitfortheSOAPClient?) how to set different Connection and Receive Timeouts. This has worked for my SOAP Service.

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(greeter);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
 
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
 
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(32000);

Comment: @harryssuperman Will this override settings that may have been set in some other way/wipe the defaults? I want everything to remain the same, just with a different receive timeout.

Comment: @lovrodoe for the Client client Object yes. You will set directly the values of the Receive Timeout. i have changed Connection Timeout and ReceiveTimeout in my case.